# Why is my PhotoComponent not updating with the correct photos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here is App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';
import Nav from './Nav';
import '../index.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import apiKey from './Config';
import NotFound from './NotFound';
import PhotoList from './PhotoList';


class App extends Component {

  state= {
    pictures: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getImages()
  }


  getImages=(query='cats')=> {
    axios.get(`https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=${apiKey}&tags=${query}&per_page=24&page=1&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`)
      .then(res=> {
        const pictures=res.data.photos.photo
        this.setState({pictures});
      }).catch((error)=> {
        console.log("There was an error parsing your data", error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pictures);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Search />
        <Nav getImages={this.getImages}  />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <Redirect to={'/cats'} />} />
          <Route path='/cats' render={()=> <PhotoList getImages={()=>this.getImages} query='cats' data={this.state.pictures}/>} />
          <Route path='/dogs' render={()=> <PhotoList getImages={()=>this.getImages} query='dogs' data={this.state.pictures} />} />
          <Route path='/computers' render={()=> <PhotoList getImages={()=>this.getImages} query='computers' data={this.state.pictures} />} />
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is PhotoList.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Photo from './Photo';

class PhotoList extends Component {

  handleImages=()=> {
    this.props.getImages(this.props.query);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleImages();
    console.log(this.props.data)
  } 
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.props.data)
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="photo-container">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <ul>
          {this.props.data.map((photo,index)=> 
            <Photo 
              farm={photo.farm}
              server={photo.server} 
              id={photo.id}
              secret={photo.secret}
              key={index}
            />
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }   
}


export default PhotoList;
```

I've passed the `getImages` function into `PhotoList` that fetches data and changes the main App's state. The function takes a query string (cats, dogs, or computers). Then the state data is passed down as props and mapped over in the `PhotoList` component.

My website still only displays cats, even when I type in a different path (ex /dogs, /computers), yet when I console log the query string, I'm clearly entering different values into it. So why am I still getting cats shown? I know by default the query is equal to cats, but when I call the function in `PhotoList` it should be set to a different value with the query prop.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, `componentDidMount` from `PhotoList` component executes only once when component first time mounts with query `cats`.

For next route change it will not execute `componentDidMount`, and your will not get new data but the old one.

In your `componentDidUpdate` you have to check if you are getting new props and again call your `handleImages` function which calls your `getImages` function,

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log(this.props.data)
    if(prevProps.query !== this.props.query){
       this.handleImages();
    }
}
```

Another issue is `getImages` function is not getting called.

```
getImages={()=>this.getImages}
```

You should do this,

```
getImages={this.getImages}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I pasted the code into PhotoList js and unfortunately, it's still not working when I type in the different paths. Like if I type in /dogs or /computers in my browser, cats still show up.

Comment: Do `console.log(prevProps.query)` and `console.log(this.props.query)` and check you are getting new values.

Comment: @Amandeep check the updated answer, your `getImages` function itself is not getting call.

Comment: This is going to be a stupid question, but I really need the help. I can't see what's wrong with calling the function once if the corresponding query string is being passed into it. Wouldn't this simply change the state in App.js (like I wanted it to), and then from there, the component will re-render the new data coming into it? The function inside componentDidMount is being called with the correct query string, and the component simply just has to wait for data to come in from App.js.

Comment: Have you checked the updated answer? You are not actually calling the getImages function when you change routes.

Comment: Okay, so its been working so far. When I type in dog, cats will show up for a sec, then change to dog photos. One odd thing though is that the computers path still doesn't work. The computers route won't show computers at all, but when you click the nav button for it will obviously work.

Comment: For computers route, I suggest you to put default value as computers and check if data coming from API. I Doubt that data is not coming from API for computers.

Comment: Also check you type `computers` correctly, means with no typos.

Comment: Yeah so basically this is what's happening. The program is just acting super weird. If I type in a path, I may get the right photos for tha path, but then if I go to another path, and try again, then I'll get the wrong photos lol. It's essentially being super inconsistent with the types of photos it sends me. If I refresh a couple of times, the page will go back to cats. I'll try to see what's wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer that checking for changes and calling the function again might solve your problem, since getImages() only runs when the component mounts. I have some more advice that might help you organize your code better according to common practices and help you avoid this problem altogether, just by not necessitating the confusing passing around of variables between components.

- It makes the most sense to have `getImages()` part of the PhotoList component. This is  because you always need to call that function when you render a PhotoList. It's not essential to the App component. Read more about this kind of concept here: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html
- Since you are using react router, what you can do is grab the search keyword from the path, from the PhotoList component. This would look like declaring the query as `<Route path='/:query' ... >` and then in the rendered component (PhotoList), grabbing the parameter with `this.props.match.query`. Read more: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/
- If you do this, you can set default values for props using PropTypes and defaultProps. read more: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-react-default-props-5c50401ed37d

Comment: Thank you Meg. My first thought is to always put my state, whatever it may be, in the highest parent component, App.js and make data pass down from there, as I was taught that you usually do that. That's what I was trying to do here. Are you saying that this isn't always the case and that it depends on what makes sense in your particular situation?